# Remove trailing slash except for a specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The code I currently have is to remove a trailing slash from all directories in the main folder:

```
DirectorySlash Off

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME} \ /(.*)/(\ |$|\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

How can I add on an existing code to exclude the folder "myfolder"?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Add `RewriteEngine on` in top of your file.

Comment: @Hassan Good catch. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have have added answer. Please accept it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Add `RewriteEngine on` in file before `DirectorySlash Off`

```
RewriteEngine on    
DirectorySlash Off

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME} \ /(.*)/(\ |$|\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: It just doesn't exclude the folder "myfolder"

Comment: Yes I have. I have no clue why it's not working... Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You can have rules as:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on    

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME} \s/+(.+?)/[\s?]
RewriteRule !^myfolder/$ /%1 [R=301,L]

# add trailing slash for myfilder
RewriteRule ^(myfolder)$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: My domain is domain.com. When I go to any directory, for example domain.com/folder1, it does not show the trailing slash which is good. But when I go to domain.com/myfolder, the trailing slash is still not there which means the exclusion does not work.

Comment: Exact these rules are working perfectly fine on my Apache. When I enter `http://domain.com/myfolder` it becomes `http://domain.com/myfolder/`

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Why isn't it doing that for me?

Comment: Well I can't make guesses about your system, there can be many conflicts.  Make sure you don't have any other rule or any other .htaccess while testing this. And also test after clearing your browser cache completely.

Comment: I've tried everything you asked me to do and it still doesn't work.